# Using shell_exec to ftp in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, batch-file, shell-exec

I can only use shell_exec command to FTP a file to another server. This is due to the shared servers fastCGI timing out. So, no I can not use any other commands.

How do I implement it? I test the script on my PC in a DOS window and it works, but on the server using code:

```
$output = shell_exec('ftp -s:ftpscript.txt');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I get the following error:

```
ftp: s: unknown option
```

The batch file is:

```
open ftp.server.com
usernamex
passwordx
hash
cd incoming
binary
ls
```

Any ideas?

Background: I'm uploading files to Amazon AWS Glacier using PHP but large files (750Mb) time out and report a 500 Internal Server error due to the fastCGI (?) timing out. I need to find a way of uploading the large file using FTP.

Andre

Answer (score 1):

On *nix the use of the `ftp://` wrapper should not cause timeouts, because time spent on stream operations should not count towards the time limit of the script. Try calling `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the script to prevent the script from timing out.

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> **Note:**
>
> The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration directive `max_execution_time` only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using `system()`, stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

It should also be noted that transferring 750MB files over FTP from a script called via HTTP is not a good solution, because the browser will need to be kept open while the transfer completes. What you should probably be doing is either using a cron job to perform the transfer, or using an HTTP request to start the transfer asynchronously.

If this is not a viable solution for you, the problem you are running into with the `shell_exec()` approach is the difference between the Windows and *nix FTP programs.

Does your server have a command line cURL binary? This would be a much better option if it is available, because the interface is standard regardless of platform. Also, you would not need to use scripts, you can accomplish pretty much anything with command line arguments.

For example the above code could be condensed to this command:

```
$output = shell_exec('curl ftp://usernamex:passwordx@ftp.server.com/incoming/');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

This ignores the `hash` command from your script, but if you goal here is to get a directory list programmatically you should not require this option.

You can obtain a Windows cURL binary for testing on your local server [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). I would probably recommend you use the file tagged like this (it's quite a way down the page):

```
Win32   7.27.0  binary  SSL SSH Dirk Paehl
```

Full documentation for the use of the cURL command line binary can be found [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: Note from Dreamhost: When the script is loaded through the web browser, you're bound to a fastcgi limitation that appears to be timing out on the larger file. The issue here is that while on a shared hosting server, we cannot allow you to modify the fastcgi timeout. If you perform the script over the shell command line, you should not be met with the error message.

Comment: @andrebruton Do they not provide the curl command line binary? Also, do you really need to do this from a web browser (by which I mean, can't you `exec()` a PHP script to do it from the web browser and detach the process, instead of having the browser wait while the file is downloaded?)

Comment: Any idea how to code that? A working example? Can only do the transfer from a web page, no other access that I know about...

Comment: @andrebruton Can you explain the architecture a bit more so I can provide an example? You say you are uploading files, where are they coming from? Sounds like the flow is User uploads file to PHP script via HTTP -> PHP script uploads file to remote server via FTP - is this correct? If so, why do you need to list the files on the remote FTP server? Is there no way the user can upload directly to the remote server? It would save massively on bandwidth...

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom, the files are created by Dreamhost, they are the backup files created of all my hosting files etc. I have 5 days in which to move them via ftp. I have a script that logs in via ftp and downloads it to the server. From there I want to save those files on Amazon AWS. Anywhere where it is safe, retreivable and cheap. Amazon Glacier is just the solution, but they do not have a PHP library yet for doing that. I created an FTP access to Glacier using CouldGates.net online service. It works well, except for the timeout problem on the server to upload the files. Hope that helps

Comment: @andrebruton Couldn't you just run a cron job on the Dreamhost server to upload them directly to Amazon? Cut out the middleman/middleware, save bandwidth, save time, no human intervention required. Sounds like a winner to me (if possible).

Comment: Hi, I can't add a cron a job on a windows server.